# MySQL: 1064 Syntax Error

Tags: python, mysql

Hi I am working on a small program to store usernames and real names and I want to use MySQL this is my first time using it and I am following a tutorial but they have done the same as me but I get the error message below

```
1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''
```

I am also not sure which line the problem is as it just says ''

Here is my current code, when I copy the execute code into phpMyAdmin it runs when I add values

```
import MySQLdb  
Users = MySQLdb.connect('sql-.freemysqlhosting.net', 'sql4---16', 'uY---R5*', 'sql4---16')
c = Users.cursor()

Username = raw_input('Enter Username: ')
FirstName = raw_input('Enter first name: ')
LastName = raw_input('Enter last name: ')
Balance = raw_input('Enter deposit: ')

c.execute('INSERT INTO Users (Username, FirstName, LastName, Balance) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
          Username, FirstName, LastName, Balance)

Users.commit()
Users.close()
```

Comment: What about `VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)` (or whatever type do you have for the last column)?

Comment: The two quotes together means MySQL arrived at the end of your SQL statement before it found the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. The default "paramstyle" in MySQLdb is `%s`. Reference: [MySQLdb User's Guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html).
2. The second argument to `.execute()` is expected to be a sequence (e.g. tuple, list,...)

Change your query to:

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO Users (Username, FirstName, LastName, Balance) 
                  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)''', (Username, FirstName, LastName, Balance))
#                         ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^      ^                                      ^
```